# Outlook prompt - Let's get you signed in

Tags: outlook, popup, office365, outlook-2016

Every so often I am prompted to enter in my email account when Outlook prompts me to 'Let's get you signed in' when I am already signed in and connected to my Office 365 account. I am prompted every hour.

This isn't the usual prompt that appears as I can close this one and get back to working in Outlook.

- This only happens in Outlook - other Office applications do not
  prompt.
- I have moved into a new PC and the same pop up appears
- I've cleared all credentials for Office 2016 in credential manager

I am not sure what else to do. Below is a screenshot of the pop up.

**Outlook Let's get you signed in:**
[image: Outlook Let's get you signed in]

Comment: Same here ... Its quite annoying ..

Comment: @MarioMurrent this has gone away after I removed an add-on from Outlook. The add-on was Hubspot which was connected to my mailbox. I am not sure if this was the cause entirely as no one else in my organisation has the issue.

After removing it a week ago I have not had a single pop up at all like the above.

Comment: Alright thank you. I will have a look at this.